# Unicorn起動時に設定ファイルを読み込むことができません。

Tags: centos, nginx, unicorn

#### 実現したいこと

- `config/unicorn.rb`を読み込ませたい
- できれば`config/unicorn/unicorn.conf.rb`の様に一つディレクトリを挟んで配置したい

#### 前提

さくらVPSのCentOSでRails7のアプリケーションのデプロイを試みています。
デプロイ作業が慣れていない為、ローカルでUnicornを導入して正式にプルリクを上げる前に、
一旦本番サーバーに上げてある素材を使用してNginxとUnicornの導入・動作確認をしてみようとなりました。
導入までは終わり、それぞれの設定ファイルも置いて
`bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb`
を実行したところ、設定ファイルが見つからないという趣旨のエラーが発生しています。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/usr/local/rbenv/versions/3.1.3/bin/unicorn)
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/unicorn-6.1.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:613:in 
`working_directory': config_file=config/unicorn.rb would not be accessible in working_directory=/opt/sample_app (ArgumentError)
```

#### 該当のソースコード

設定ファイルの配置場所は以下です
`/opt/sample_app/config/unicorn.rb`

```rb
rails_root = "/opt/sample_app"

worker_processes 4
working_directory rails_root

listen "#{rails_root}/tmp/unicorn.sock"
pid "#{rails_root}/tmp/unicorn.pid"

stderr_path "#{rails_root}/log/unicorn_error.log"
stdout_path "#{rails_root}/log/unicorn.log"

preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('Gemfile', rails_root)
  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

権限の状況は以下の通りです。
※ 最終目標`/opt/sample_app/config/unicorn/unicorn.conf.rb`の場合の各権限ですが、unicornディレクトリを挟まないバージョンでも同じ様に権限付与しておりました。

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 user_name root 4096 Jun 26 13:04 opt

drwxr-xr-x 12 user_name root 4096 Jun 27 09:50 sample_app

drwxr-xr-x  7 user_name root  4096 Jun 27 16:05 config
drwxr-xr-x  2 user_name root  4096 Jun 27 10:10 log
drwxr-xr-x  5 user_name root  4096 Jun 27 10:09 tmp

drwxr-xr-x 2 user_name root 4096 Jun 27 17:12 unicorn

-rw-r--r-- 1 user_name root 1101 Jun 27 17:12 unicorn.conf.rb
```

#### 試したこと

色々ググって以下のことを試してみました。

- Unicorn起動時のパスが合っているか確認
- 各ディレクトリ、ファイルの権限を確認
- 当初`config/unicorn/unicorn.conf.rb`の様に一つディレクトリを挟んでいたので、config直下に移動

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

【環境】
さくらVPS
CentOS Stream 9
Nginx 1.22.1
Unicorn 6.1.0
MySQL(MariaDB)
Ruby 3.1.3
Ruby on Rails 7.0.4

私なりにググってみたりChatGPTを使ってみたりしましたが、
大体「パスが間違っていた」「権限がなかった」という記事しか見つからず、
パスは合っていると思われ、権限もおそらく大丈夫だと思うのですが、
エラーが解消できず詰まっております。
ご教授の程、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

こちら解決しました。
やはりパスが問題で、`/opt/sample_app`となっていますが、こちらは`/home`からのパスが必要だった様でした。
ありがとうございました。